# Azure DevOps- Pull Request- Unable to merge code into master because the development branch has more than 100 commits

Tags: azure-devops, git-branch, git-commit, pull-request

I have created a "development" branch based on "master" to work on the development tasks. In the "development" branch, I committed the code multiple times to complete the few development tasks. Finally, my branch contains more than 100 commits.

After a few days, I created a pull request from "development" to "master" in Azure DevOps. Whenever I am trying to complete the active pull request, it gives the below error:

"Unable to merge code into master because the development branch has more than 100 commits"

Comment: What does this message mean? The Azure DevOps PR will only take the first 100 commits and remaining is lost?
"This pull request will merge over 100 commits into master. Double check the source and target branches to make sure this is intentional. Work items only from the first 100 commits will be linked."